# Method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: ios, swift

I try to implement two methods in viewcontroller

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
}
```

but I cannot because I get an error for second method that says

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

If i remove override keyword I also get an error saying

[image]

What have I to do ?

Comment: It is probably because the method signature changed. It returns now a `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` instead of an `Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New syntax for swift 2.0:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Check [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) for more Info.